# Ruby on Rails 3: has_and_belongs_to_many two distinct models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two models; team and project. The application I am trying to create lets the team to create a new project. Sometimes, a team can do a joint project with another team.

So what is the correct association that I should use between them?
Right now, I have

team.rb

```
has_many :projects
```

project.rb

```
belongs_to :team
```

I am not sure if "has_and_belongs_to_many" association will do since [RoR guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) uses two model plus a weak model

Answer (score 0):

You can use the has_and_belongs_to_many association with two models if you also create a join table like so:

```
class AddTeamsProjectsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :teams_projects, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer :teams_id
    t.integer :projects_id
  end
end

  def self.down
    drop_table :teams_projects
  end
end
```

Then in your models:

team.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```

project.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
```

Then you can access all the projects for one team using @team.projects, or all the teams for one project with @project.teams